# Strange Audio Issues Triggered by MuseScore and OpenShot

Tags: audio, nvidia, alsa, zorin

I'm using Zorin OS 16.2.

The problem is simple. Whenever I play back any audio whilst editing in OpenShot 3.0.0, it appears to play really fast, condensing a four-minute audio clip to 28 seconds. As a result, the audio is completely unintelligible and distorted.

Likewise, any sample played by MuseScore 4.0.2 seems to be incredibly sped up to the point that a note just sounds like a short sample of white noise. In the case of MuseScore, the playback header moves really fast regardless of tempo indicated. I imagine this is because MuseScore receives feedback from the OS as to when an individual note sample has finished playing (which is really brief).

Any other audio plays back just fine even whilst the above two programs are playing audio of their own.

I've noticed that observing Settings > Sound whilst playing back audio through either program or shortly thereafter will cause a graphical glitch in that particular menu seemingly caused by "ALSA plug-in [python3.10]" appearing and disappearing very quickly under "Volume Levels." It also seems to be that the issue is resolved by simply allowing either program to run for a few minutes, after which "ALSA plug-in [mscore]" and "ALSA plug-in [python3.10]" appear (for each program respectively) under "Volume Levels" without flickering. Restarting the programs resets the issue.

If it is helpful in any way, I have an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 3GB plugged to my TV which I am using as a monitor via HDMI. This is also what I am using for audio output, primarily.

I recorded the issue as described above [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UaSKqNXZmhw).

My question is: how do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to U&L . Unfortunately this is a bit unclear. If you import a 41KHz sample into a project with 96KHz sample rate, it will be played back shorter and higher, which is what this sounds like. MuseScore and OpenShot both default to 41KHz, so check what sample rate your audio interface is set to - it needs to match. If that doesn't resolve it, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/742108/edit) the question and add exact workflow how this could be reproduced. Adding example project and files would also help.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I'm not too sure what you mean by "audio interface," but I did check the sample rate between a test audio clip and the OpenShot's playback sample rate-- they match. I've added a video recording of the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.